# How to find difference between two .cs files in Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, diff

Is there any way find difference between two cs files. I already ask question in which I ask about XML file now I want to compare two .cs files in visual studio. is there any command like linux to find difference in windows?

Comment: Do you have any source control software installed? That usually comes with a file comparer.

Comment: Download and install [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) or any other diff tool.

Comment: Are you looking for a textual or semantic difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the *official* tool Visual Studio comes with a **very** simple comparison utility: `diffmerge`. You can use it both to compare and to merge files. It's located in the Common7\IDE folder under the Visual Studio installation path. Syntax is simple (for basic operations) and it can be used both from command line (simply run the command to see the syntax) and with UI (as used by Visual Studio itself as default comparison utility for source files under source control).

Answer (score 1):

windiff is installed with visual studio as far as I remember

EDIT:
actually its installed with the windows SDK - but can be downloaded seperately - but i find Beyond Compare by far the best tool - but not free.

Answer (score 1):

The excellent free WinMerge is probably more useful then windiff.

http://winmerge.org/